# How to return a ES6 Map Object after using reduce() to count instances of values in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm just beginning to learn JavaScript and this is a part of my Take-home exam, and the requirement is quite tricky for me.

We have many ways to counting instances of values in an object in JS, but in here I have to achieve it by calling `reduce()` and return an ES6 map object.

Here is the requirement:

```
/**
* Takes an array of items, and returns a Map with the
* frequencies (counts) of each item in the array.
*
* Must do this by using a single call to reduce.
*
* For example,
*  freqs([1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1]) returns Map {1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 1, 7 => 1}
*  freqs("One fish two fish red fish blue fish".split(' '))
*  returns Map {"One" => 1, "fish" => 4, "two" => 1, "red" => 1, "blue" => 1}
*/
```

And here's my code so far:

```
function freqs(items) {
  var map = new Map();
  return items.reduce(function(allkey, key) {
    if (map.has(key)) {
      var value = map.get(key);
      map.set(key, value++);
    } else {
      map.set(key, 1);
    }
    return map;
  }, {})
}
```

I used debugger and found out that on `map.set(key, value++)` is not overwriting the new value in the `map` when it iterates. Why?

So when I input `C = [1,2,3,2,7,2,1];` the output is always like this:

```
Map(4) {1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 7 => 1}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, this is a weird application of `reduce`. The correct way would be to pass the map as initial value (instead of the object literal) and rename the first argument from `allkey` to `map`.

Comment: @Rafael OH dude I should delete that

Comment: You also need to do a table lookup on every iteration, asking if the map entry exists and initialize the entry to 0 otherwise, and increment every time.

Comment: @Rafael: They are doing that. `if (map.has(key)) {`

Comment: Hint to solve your actual problem: Look at what `value++` does (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

Comment: @FelixKling true!

Comment: @FelixKling If I try to do that it will raise an error `higher-hw.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: map.has is not a function`

Comment: Very nice question statement ;) Couldn't only hope that every question had this much info. @TravisSu don't forget to return your `allkeys`

Comment: @Icepickle ummm why?

Comment: @TravisSu: Then you are not doing exactly what I said ;) `return items.reduce(function(map, key) { /*...*/ return map; }, new Map());`.

Comment: @TravisSu: *"ummm why?"* Because that's how `.reduce` is normally supposed to be used (at least in a case like yours). Of course that only works if you pass the correct initial value, as I have shown in my previous comment.

Comment: @TravisSu Because it is your accumulator, see the MDN of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

Comment: @Icepickle: The way the OP's code is written, returning `allkeys` would be wrong though.

Comment: @FelixKling I was already following with map as an input parameter as you suggested :D

Comment: @FelixKling ;) modified as your suggestion, but still producing `Map(4) {1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 7 => 1}`

Comment: @TracisSu: Sure, because that's not the source of your problem. Seems like you missed [this comment of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699654/how-to-return-a-es6-map-object-after-using-reduce-to-count-instances-of-values?noredirect=1#comment80346755_46699654): *"Hint to solve your actual problem: Look at what `value++` does"*

Comment: `++value` or `value + 1`

Comment: @FelixKling so the reason why its not overwriting is because when I use postfix it will returns 1 before it increment to 2, then it will always shows 1 on the output.

Comment: @TravisSu: Basically yes. You *are* overwriting the value... but always with the same value.

Comment: @FelixKling after some experiments I also found out `++value` doesn't work either but `value + 1` works, why is that?

Comment: @Icepickle `++value` doesn't work either but `value + 1` works, interesting.

Comment: `++value` works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/9j1zr9fg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `a++` returns the value of `a` before adding `1`:

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(a++);
console.log(a);
```

Since `Map#set` returns the map after being modified, you can simplify your code like this:

```js
function freqs(items) {
  return items.reduce(
    (map, e) => map.set(e, (map.get(e) || 0) + 1),
    new Map()
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you may use the somewhat obscure and rarely seen increment operator prefix, which also increments the variable, but returns the incremented new version of it:

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(++a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Your code is exacty what @FelixKling suggests but since he didn't post the Answer so I'm gonna vote this anyways, thanks for your guys help.